# Does tmp_name get destroyed when user goes to another php page?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

Do `$_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"];` get destroyed if the user goes to another php page?

I am trying to pass the tmp_name in a hidden form field to the actual submit function where the tmp_name is copied to the server.

So this is my flow:
User Submits forms -> User confirms submission (all $_POST are added to hidden fields) -> Once confirmed the data is submitted and the file is `copy()` to server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File uploads work like this:

- user submits form, uploading file to server
- PHP stores received file data in /tmp directory, putting the file name into the `$_FILES` array of the script
- PHP executes your script, you do with the data whatever you want
- when your script is done, PHP will clean up the uploaded file data from the /tmp directory if it still exists there

So yes, uploaded files are only available for a single script execution. If you need them later, move them to a more permanent location.

And do not pass that file location to the user, even through hidden form fields. That's client-side data, which means the user can manipulate the data and possibly cause security breaches by pointing the file path somewhere he has no business.

Comment: That confirms why I am having issues.